# Converting raw numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm having trouble converting 10500.37 as a currency to $10,500.37 using Oracle. I'm currently using Oracle SQL developer.

This is what I did:

SELECT to_number('10500.37','$10,500.37')
FROM Dual;

Not sure how to fix this and if Im using the format model properly. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting a number to a formatted string, so you need `to_char()` rather than `to_number()` (which converts the other way).

This is one possible format model:

```
SELECT to_char(10500.37, 'L999G990D00') FROM Dual;

TO_CHAR(1050
------------
  $10,500.37
```

You need enough leading 9 placeholders (and group separators) for the highest value you will have to deal with.

The number format models [are listed in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211).

I've used G for the group separator (rather than hard-coding a comma) and D for the decimal separator (rather than hard-coding a period). And I've used L for the local currency symbol. All of those depend on the client's NLS settings:

```
alter session set nls_territory='UNITED KINGDOM';

SELECT to_char(10500.37, 'L999G990D00') FROM Dual;

TO_CHAR(10500.37,'L99
---------------------
          £10,500.37

alter session set nls_territory='GERMANY';

SELECT to_char(10500.37, 'L999G990D00') FROM Dual;

TO_CHAR(10500.37,'L99
---------------------
         €10.500,37

alter session set nls_territory='AMERICA';

SELECT to_char(10500.37, 'L999G990D00') FROM Dual;

TO_CHAR(10500.37,'L99
---------------------
           $10,500.37
```

You *may* want to use fixed values instead, for some or all of those, so you get the same output regardless of NLS settings:

```
alter session set nls_territory='GERMANY';

SELECT to_char(10500.37, '$999,990.00') FROM Dual;

TO_CHAR(1050
------------
  $10,500.37
```

Comment: More generally, to have a currency symbol independent of the session's NLS parameters, `to_char()` takes the argument `'nls_currency=<symbol>'`. This is needed especially when the currency symbol is not $ (as $ can be used directly in the format model; not so for other symbols).